# How to trigger the animation of a GLB in A-frame

Tags: 3d, aframe

This puppy has animations https://poly.pizza/m/y4wdQpg767

**I'm trying to trigger the attack animation in the HTML with A-frame: 1.4.0**

**And with JS 2D**

```
perrito = document.getElementById('perrito');
perrito.addEventListener('click', function () {
      perrito.setAttribute('animation-mixer', "clip : Attack, loop : repeat, repetitions : indefinite");
});
```

**And with JS 3D is two ways**

1.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('ataque', {
   init: function () {
      el.addEventListener('click', function () {
             el.setAttribute('animation-mixer', "clip : Attack, loop : repeat, repetitions : indefinite");
       });
      }
});
```

2. 

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('ataque2', {
     init: function () {
         el.addEventListener('click', function () {
             el.setAttribute('animation-mixer', {'clip': 'Attack', 'loop': 'repeat', 'repetitions': 'indefinite'});
         });
       }
});
```

But the dog does not attack... why?

Answer (score 0):

Try it without any arguments like follow:

```
el.setAttribute('animation-mixer', {
  clip: "Walk"
});
```

Comment: if I make this: setAttribute('animation-mixer', {clip : "Walk"}); This is the results: <a-entity id="perrito" position="2 0 -6" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5" gltf-model="assets/perrito.glb" andar="" animation-mixer="[object Object]"></a-entity> You can see the code: https://signados.github.io/a-frame-basics/index.html | https://github.com/signados/a-frame-basics

Answer (score 0):

I need the script: `<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v4.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>`

This functionality is extra

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).